# Using \foreach to make a network graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, foreach

I am tying to make this hand drawn network:

[image: Expected]

In the process of making this graph, I am also trying to learn loops. I am trying to use `\foreach` here. This is the code I have managed so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a in {1,2,...,6}
\foreach \b in {CA\\144,BC\\221,KM\\44,LG\\22,KP\\444,X\\71}{
\draw (\a*360/6: 4cm) node [circle, draw=black]{angle \b};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the corresponding output:

[image: Current output]

I am unable to find a way to separate the node, label them, and then move to the next step where I need to add the arrows and numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue in your foreach combination. I suggest the following:

[image: using foreach to draw graph]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>={Stealth[length=3mm, width=2mm]}]
        \foreach \b/\angle [count=\a] in {CA/144,BC/221,KM/44,LG/22,KP/444,X/71}{
        \draw (\a*360/6: 4cm) node [circle, draw=black, text width=18mm, align=center] (\a) {angle \b \\ \angle};
    }
        \draw[->] (1) -- (2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. But how do I address each node now to draw the arrows? Usually, I label each node, so I can follow that up with `\arrow` and point one node to the next. Over here, this may not be possible, right?

Comment: You have to name them. I edited my answer.